# Parallel execution of Selenium Tests with MSTest , C# and Selenium Grid

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, selenium-webdriver, mstest, selenium-grid

We have a web application which we have automated using the Page Object model, Web Driver and C# bindings using MSTest. Now we are planning to use Selenium grid to schedule these tests on multiple nodes for parallel execution.

Basically we want to run tests on all the available nodes in parallel. I came to know that with TestNG it is easy as it provides a built in support for the parallel execution using the config file approach.

How we can achieve the same if the framework is written using the MSTest and C# bindings of Web Driver ?.

If you have any ideas of references please let me know

Comment: this link should answer your query http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Anuragh27crony. I am aware of this facility in the VSTS but what i am looking for i have Ui automated tests written in Selenium now i want to run them in parallel on different browsers on different systems. Tools like MBUnit, TestNg etc have support for this but i cant change my test suite to those frameworks as its too much of investment.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that for C#, you should use [pNUnit](http://www.plasticscm.com/infocenter/technical-articles/pnunit.aspx).   Maybe [NUnitMerger](https://github.com/15below/NUnitMerger) would be useful also if you do that.    The parallel tools for the Java world are way way superior IMHO than the C# world.